# Access denied using the STSADM command

Tags: stsadm, error, permissions

I am unable to use the STSADM command. When i try to use it, it shows me access denied.

I am the admin of my system, but still I am getting access denied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you running Server 2008?  If so, you need to open the command prompt using the "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: User Access Control will prevent you from running commands unless you do the "Run As" that Mark suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Add your user account to the Administrators group on the Local Machine. Make sure the BUILTIN\Administrators is in the Farm Administration group.

Central Administration -> Operations -> Update farm administrator's group

Comment: yeah i have been added to admin list.still same "access denied"

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as a local administrator of the system? Also, you must be logged in to the SharePoint server via a remote desktop or local connection; you cannot "remotely" administer a SharePoint farm with stsadm.

Comment: yes i have been logged in as administrator.But i m remotely accessing the PC.Is this an issue?

Comment: As long as you log in remotely with an account that is a member of the Administrators group on the system, you should be fine (as in, issue isn't with remote desktop connection).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Folder where the backup file will store and should not readonly. if yes uncheck from folder properte and try again. its working for me. Thank you, Eugine

Comment: Backup file? How does your answer relate to the question about running STSADM? Perhaps you need to add more details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start the cmd prompt with elevated privileges or you'll get access denied
("run as admin")